# nested views of main CT and sub CT

Tags: views, nodes

What I want to achieve is nested view.

Say I have Content Type 'main' en Content Type 'sub'

How can I create a view that looks like this:

```
main 1 title
main 1 fields
    sub 1 title
    sub 1 fields

    sub 2 title
    sub 2 fields

    ...

main 2 title
main 2 fields
    sub 4 title
    sub 4 fields

    sub 5 title
    sub 5 fields 

    ...

...
```

Do I need references?

more context:
I know there is something like entity-reference and also the use of tags.
For every sub I placed 'main 1', 'main 2' or 'main 3' as a tag.
I also let every sub refer to content 'main 1' , 'main 2' or 'main 3' with the entity reference (set on main)
I tried already by creating a view of 'main' and a block view for each 'sub' with tag as extra filter. I don't know though how to make the view 'main' implement each 'sub' view and place it in each main node.
Is this clear or do you need more info? If so, which ?

Comment: yes it stands for content type

Comment: What do you mean by "references", and why do you think so? What are you trying to do/achieve? What did you try, and what kind of problem did you run into? Please EDIT your question to make that more clear (do not add an extra comment to make that clear). If we don't understand the question, we cannot answer it, OK? FYI: just trying to HELP ...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Views Accordion](http://drupal.org/project/views_accordion) module, and its related [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/366263).

By "grouping fields", the group header can be used as accordion header. And Views allows for one field to include the content of multiple fields, so you can utilize this views feature for this purpose (Combined fields).

Does this help somehow?

Comment: I tried it and the view is nested indeed, but it looks like a table and you have to manualy open each node.

Comment: the grouper also only shows the title and I want the body and other fields of the grouper to be shown also